# Can I get in trouble for not giving Oracle credit in my Java game?

Tags: software, attribution

So I was planning on making a game for my favorite Youtuber, and I'm not sure if I will get into trouble with Oracle (since I am making it in Java) if I don't give credit to them for using their programming language. I couldn't find anything on the internet for this, so don't get mad at me if this is obvious. I just want to be sure I'm not going to have to deal with some legal stuff.

P.S. If you know a place to upload JAR files so people may download them, feel free to tell me. It would also help to know how I can make sure that nobody steals my game and takes credit for it. This isn't as important as what is above, so you don't need to answer it.

Comment: You literally cannot prevent someone from stealing your game and trying to take credit. You _can_, however, demonstrate unequivocally that you were the _first_ person to upload the game, and so are most likely the original author. You don't need to credit Oracle, because, well... No one else does. As long as you aren't making money from the game, there's pretty much a zero percent probability you'll have any legal trouble over it. Plus, if you compile it with OpenJDK, you don't need to rely on Oracle. Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the [Oracle Binary Licence Agreement](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html) doesn't say much.

If you're really concerned, it's better to be safe than sorry. Just add a quick note, *this app was written with Java!*, but make sure not to make it look as if Oracle endorses/promotes the app.

---

If you're willing to release the source code and binaries, you may like Github. You may have fun looking around, learning about Open Source. It's a popular licensing model that allows people to use libraries for a variety of uses.